# How can i update my codenameone plugin and handed to the latest classes update

Tags: java, codenameone

I update the codenameone frequently but I have a problem I don't have some classes or functions for example I have only three classes in `com.codename1.ui.geom` such as: `Dimension`, `Point` and `Rectangle` classes but not the others or in `graphics.class` I don't have function named `setTransform`. what should I do?

Thanks in advance.

Updated:

[image: my currently version]

[image: i don't have Matrix class]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click the project select project properties and client Update Client Libs button:

[image]

Comment: Thank you i click on this button but it doesn't make it updated.

Comment: Then you are currently up to date for this project. The latest version at this moment is 76, you can see the current version for the project in the codenameone_settings.properties file.

Comment: my version was 75. even if i update the plugin from update part of netbeans after restarting netbeans codenameone plugin break and doesn't work and i have to reset my netbeans and install cn1 again yeah after whole this my version become 76 but it's hard to update every time like this.

Comment: Are you behind a firewall or proxy?

Comment: I suggest updating the proxy settings in JavaSE rather than in NetBeans, how do builds work for you without doing that?

Comment: Thank you, I don't have any problem with that part. But i still doesn't have the matrix class in my codenameone library.

Comment: Did the update work, did you get version 76? 
Assuming you are using the latest NetBeans version do you have these methods in a newly created project?

Comment: yes my currently version is 76 but still i don't have it. look at my images above in updated part.

Comment: If you type in setTransform with the right syntax does it compile with the project marked as 76? If so the problem is in NetBeans and you should flush its caches.