# Why do I get a different behviour in Codename One simulator than on a real Android device?

Tags: drawing, codenameone, simulator

I am trying to figure out why I get a different behaviour in the simulator (iPhone, Nexus, Nexus5, ... skins ) VS on an Android real device with the following code (my goal is to draw a text over a background image and save the whole in background image resolution) :

*Please note that the GUI was done with the Designer.*

```
    protected void beforeMain(Form f) {

    // The drawing label will contain the whole photo montage
    f.setLayout(new LayeredLayout());
    final Label drawing = new Label();
    f.addComponent(drawing);

    String nom = "Hello World";

    // Image mutable dans laquelle on va dessiner (fond blancpar défaut)
    // synthe is an Image
    Image mutableImage = Image.createImage(synthe.getWidth(), synthe.getHeight());
    drawing.getUnselectedStyle().setBgImage(mutableImage);
    drawing.getUnselectedStyle().setBackgroundType(Style.BACKGROUND_IMAGE_SCALED_FIT);

    // Draws over the background image and put all together on the mutable image.
    paintSyntheOnBackground(mutableImage.getGraphics(), 
            synthe,
            nom,
            synthe.getWidth(), 
            synthe.getHeight());

    long time = new Date().getTime();
    OutputStream os;
    try {
        os = Storage.getInstance().createOutputStream("screenshot_" + Long.toString(time) + ".png");
        ImageIO.getImageIO().save(mutableImage, os, ImageIO.FORMAT_PNG, 1.0f);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

} // end of beforeMain
```

And here is the method I call to draw a text over an image

```
public void paintSyntheOnBackground(Graphics g, 
        Image synthe,
        final String pNom,
        int width, int height) {

     Font myFont = g.getFont();
        g.setFont(myFont);
        int w = myFont.stringWidth(pNom);
        int h = myFont.getHeight();

        // Added just to see the background
        g.setColor(0x0000FF);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);

        g.setColor(0xff0000);
        int x = g.getTranslateX() + width / 2 - w / 2;
        int y = g.getTranslateY() + height / 2 - h / 2;

        g.drawRect(x, y, w, h);
        g.drawString(pNom, x, y);

} // end of paintSyntheOnBackground
```

Here is the outcome on the simulator (GoogleNexus7) :
[image: outcome on the simulator (GoogleNexus7)]

And here is the outcome on the device (Android 4.4) :
[image: outcome on the device (Android 4.4)]

My development system features Eclipse on Linux with Codename One V3-4.

I know the simulator cannot reproduce specific case, but here there is nothing special isn't it ? What can I do to make the behaviour on the simulator reflect the real behaviour since it would be much handier to test in the simulator ?

*EDIT : After upgrading each of my CN1 project libs from version 114 to 115 (see [this question for details on how to do the upgrade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24993130/how-can-i-update-my-codenameone-plugin-and-handed-to-the-latest-classes-update)), I am now able to get the same behaviour in both simulator and device! Great bug fixing job CN1 team! 
Please note : In my case (Eclipse - Linux) I had to upgrade the project libs in **each and every** Codename One project.*

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Cheers,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a really annoying bug that we [just fixed now](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/commit/65ad28c2b2b9bffe5156783b5c012f6b48ba7192) so it can make it to today's release.

The problem only occurs when drawing on a mutable image in a case where the simulator is in scale mode both of which we don't do often as scale mode is less accurate and mutable images are generally slower.

Thanks for keeping up with this.

Comment: You do really rock Codename One Team! You can't image how easier you make my life with this bug fixed! I updated to version 115 and it now works as expected. Thank you so much @Shai!

Comment: Thanks for keeping up with this issue ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the fix. I was having the same problem. I just chose to ignore it, because it worked fine on an actual device, but it's certainly helpful that this is fixed.